# pyodbc has a .pyi file but mypy doesn't see the stub file

Tags: pytest, pyodbc, mypy, stub

pyodbc has a [.pyi file](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/master/src/pyodbc.pyi) but when running `pytest-mypy`, I have this error:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________ connexion.py __________________________________________________________________________________________________
3: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "pyodbc"
3: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
_
```

This should only happen when the library doesn't have stub files but it appears there are stub files. What should I do?

I'm using `Python 3.10.2` and i've updated pyodbc to the latest version (`pyodbc==4.0.34`)

Comment: This is a bug in the pyodbc lib, see https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/925

Comment: Not sure I understand any of what's discussed there :(

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your python is installed in `/usr`. In that case, your python executable will be in `/usr/bin`, and any libraries you install with `pip` will be installed in `/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages`. In this case, all the sources for `pyodbc` can be found in `/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodbc`.

Following this pattern we would expect to find type stubs in `/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodbc.pyi`, but there is an issue in `pyodbc`, so that the stubs are actually installed in `/usr/pyodbc.pyi`.

In order to pick up this path, you will need to modify settings in your development environment. In Linux, try setting `PYTHONPATH=/usr` in your environment. The link mentioned in rogdham's comment includes others' comments on how to make this work in VS Code. Other development environments should support similar workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I move the stub file from /usr/pyodbc.pyi to /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodbc.pyi manually? Also, it does sound easy to fix, why is this issue still opened? (I don't know anything about creating packages so it might not be easy to fix)

Comment: you should be able to move it manually. It's easy enough to try, at least

Comment: In site-packages I only have the folder `pyodbc-4.0.34.dist-info` is this normal?

Comment: All the pyodbc.py files are in sqlachemy, but there are several `pyodbc.py` files, so I don't really know where to put the corresponding `pyodbc.pyi` file?